# How can i optimize Bitmap Heap Scan in PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, query-optimization, database-optimization

This is my explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/iR8X

I have an index on orders.account_id and orders.completion_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an index scan, which is much faster, if you create a multi-column index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON orders(orders_account_id, orders_brand_id);
```

The same holds for the other branch of the query, but since that is only executed once, it won't matter so much.

Further optimizations could only be suggested if we knew the query.